# Help interpreting standardized residual after Chi2-test

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals

After chi2-test I could reject the null hypothesis. Using the observed and expected values I calculated the residuals for each component and put them in a dataframe, see figure below.

Am I thinking correctly if I say *Bank transfer (automatic)* is **more** likely to say *Yes* due to value 17.699? This will also lead that *Bank transfer (automatic)* is **less** likely to say *No* due to  residuel -10.637?

[image]

Comment: Residuals are typically an array with multiple values. What is the meaning of a single value? Is it the L$_2$ norm of residuals?

Comment: @Carl The values are calcultated by (observed-expected)/sqrt(expected)

Comment: What you calculated are called [Pearson residuals](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/86/). Cells with positive residuals had higher than expected counts and vice-versa. It is usually recommended to inspect the standardized residuals which follow a large-sample standard normal distribution. In that way, it's easy to compare the residuals and their magnitude.